# Performance issues when using Jquery Datatable in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jquery, json, datatable

I am currently using Jquery Datatable in Sharepoint, where I am not using ajax in datatable as I am fetching data from multiple tables and after doing than I am joining the list and converting it to object array. I am fetching data using rest and jquery promises. Once done and table is created I am converting this html table to jquery datatable. 
In IE11 for 1000 records it takes 10 seconds and in chrome 3 seconds. 
Please let me know if any help can be provided.

Comment: As per information in the question, I would like to know is there any business reason fetch 1000 records at a time instead of having pagination?

Comment: I have enabled paging for showing 50 records at a time but the html table is created for 1000 records

Comment: Using REST Api you can get the 50 records in a single call versus getting 1000 records at a time and show 50 on each click. This will increase performance and reduce the page size. Let me know if you need help on this?

Comment: Actually I m fetching data from multiple list and then joining data between lists by comparing id's. Once then an array of object is created. If I fetch 50 records at a time this will be difficult to match records and also I have filters on top of columns so how will all this work

Comment: Got it. Coming to your problem you can find the time it is taking for each call from the browser developer tool from Network tab. This will help you to fine tune the particular portion.